# Three.js alpha materials and tweening

Tags: three.js, tween.js

I've started using Three.js just yeasterday and I have bumped into problem with tweening. I figured out how to hack example with draggable cube to control rotation with keyboard arrows. Works just fine. But problem is alpha. I tried to hack it with custom function with lot of this:

```
if(someBoolean == 1){object.material.opacity -= someFloat;}
```

and it works, but once I try doing this:

```
case KEYUP:
new TWEEN.Tween(cubeOpacity).to(0).start();
console.log("tweening opacity to 0");
```

nope, not gonna happen. Console says nothing is wrong, but tweening goes on forever, it stays at value 1. And  have no idea why. And writing some function for chaning opacity of every single element seems to be against DRY philosophy, so... meh.

Here is entire code:

```html
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tween.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/keys.js"></script>

<script>

    var container, stats;
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var cube;


    var centerX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var centerY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    init();
    animate();

    function init(){

        container = document.createElement( 'div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);

        var info = document.createElement ('div');
        info.style.position = 'absolute';
        info.style.top = '10px';
        info.style.width = '100%';
        info.style.textAlign = 'center';
        info.innerHTLM = 'Drag to spin';
        container.appendChild(info);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
        camera.position.y = 150;
        camera.position.z = 500;

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // Cube 

        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200, 10, 10, 10);

        for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i+= 3 ) {
            var hex = Math.random() * 0xffffff;
            geometry.faces[i].color.setHex(hex);
            geometry.faces[i+1].color.setHex(hex+100);

        }   
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: 0.5, transparent: true, opacity: 1.0 } );

        cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        cube.position.y = 150;
        scene.add(cube);


        // Plane 

        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 200, 200, 10, 10 );
        geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(- Math.PI / 2));

        var materialBottom = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xe0e0e0, overdraw: 0.5 } );
        plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialBottom);
        scene.add(plane);


        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyPressed, false);          

    }
    function onWindowResize(){

        centerX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        centerY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    }
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        render();
    }

    function render() {

        TWEEN.update();
        if (TWEEN.update()) {   

            console.log(TWEEN.update());
            console.log(cube.material.opacity);
        }
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }

    function onKeyPressed (event) {
        var key = event.keyCode;
        if (!TWEEN.update()) {
            switch( key )
            {
                case KEYLEFT:

                new TWEEN.Tween(cube.rotation).to( {
                    x: 0,
                    y: cube.rotation.y + 90 * (Math.PI/180),
                    z: 0 }, 750 )
                .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut).start();

                new TWEEN.Tween(plane.rotation).to( {
                    x: 0,
                    y: plane.rotation.y + 90 * (Math.PI/180),
                    z: 0 }, 1000 )
                .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut).start();
                console.log("tweenLeft");
                break;

                case KEYRIGHT:

                new TWEEN.Tween(cube.rotation).to( {
                    x: 0,
                    y: cube.rotation.y -90 * (Math.PI/180),
                    z: 0 }, 750 )
                .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut).start();

                new TWEEN.Tween(plane.rotation).to( {
                    x: 0,
                    y: plane.rotation.y -90 * (Math.PI/180),
                    z: 0 }, 1000 )
                .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut).start();
                console.log("tweenRight");
                break;   

                case KEYUP:
                new TWEEN.Tween(cube.material.opacity).to(0).start();
                console.log("tweenAlpha");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

So, does anybody knows where the problem is? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
new TWEEN.Tween( cube.material ).to( { opacity: 0 }, 1000 ).start();
```